# Как отключить скрипт для мобильной версии сайта?

Tags: jquery

Как отключить скрипт для мобильной версии сайта?

Answer (score 2):

```
// делаете переменную в начале кода
var isMobile = false;
// проверка на размер экрана (размер я брал вроде с Bootstrap-а)
$(document).ready( function() {
    if ($('body').width() <= 400) {
        isMobile = true;
    }
    // и потом если нужен код только для телефона:
    if (isMobile) {
        ...
    }
    // или для остальных
    if (!isMobile) {
        ...
    }
} );
```

Comment: Поправил. isMobile сделана глобальной для использования не только в document.ready, но и в других событиях.

Answer (score 2):

Запустит скрипт по указанному адресу если разрешение больше мобильной версии сайта - размера экрана 460

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if (screen.width > 480) document.write ('
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/wow.min.js" ></sc' + 'ript>
   ');

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[$(window).resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Узнаёте нужный вам размер окна, и скрипт будет работать только при выполнении условия, т.е. нужного размера окна:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    width = $(window).width();
    if (width >= 991) {
        //ваши скрипты
    }
});
```