# Отключение скрипта в мобильной версии сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

Есть скрипт аудиоплеера, мне нужно чтобы в мобильной версии сайта аудиодорожка заменялась на иконку `play/pause`, для этого мне нужно  отключать этот скрипт. У меня в моем примере все работает как нужно, мне только нужно понять как отключать скрипт, т.к мой вариант нижу я не могу использовать потому что полетят другие штуки на сайте. Как это сделать?  Я делал так:

css:

```
@media all and (max-width:1170px) {
    .clan {
        display: block;
    }
    .player {
        display: none;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #button {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
    }
}
@media all and (min-width: 1170px) {
    .clan {
        display: none;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

html:

```
<div class="player hidden-player">
    <div class="audio-title">
        <p>Some text</p>
        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></a>
    </div>
    <audio preload="auto" controls>
        <source src="assets/audio.mp3" />
        <source src="assets/audio.ogg" />
        <source src="assets/audio.wav" />
    </audio>
</div>
<div class="clan" onclick="togglePlay(this)">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149668.svg" id="button" >
    <audio src="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mp3/bachfugue.mp3"></audio>                                            
</div>
```

js:

```
'use strict';
let playIcon = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149668.svg";
let pauseIcon = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149670.svg";
function togglePlay(elm) {
  var audio = elm.querySelector('audio');
  if(!audio) return;

  elm.querySelector('img').src = audio.paused ? playIcon : pauseIcon;
}
```

Я знаю, что [здесь уже писали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549792/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0), но я не понимаю как решить проблему. Я копипастил весь код из `audioplayer.js` в `if`, но не помогло. Помогите решить.
Полный пример [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/n1w5huy0/2/). У

Comment: ну, во-первых, у Вас ($this) неправильно написан - надо $(this)

Comment: @humster_spb, исправил, но не помогло(

Comment: @humster_spb помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего задать Вашему скрипту какой-то id и при определённой ширине экрана добавлять/удалять значение в src. При этом проверку ширины экрана надо проводить не только при resize, но, в первую очередь, при загрузке:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(this).width() < 494) {
      $('#script').attr('src', '')
      console.log($('#script').attr('src'));
    }
    else {
      $('#script').attr('src', 'js/audioplayer.js');
      console.log($('#script').attr('src'));
    }
 })
 $(window).resize(function(){
    if($(this).width() < 494) {
      $('#script').attr('src', '')
      console.log($('#script').attr('src'));
    }
    else {
      $('#script').attr('src', 'js/audioplayer.js');
      console.log($('#script').attr('src'));
    }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='js/audioplayer.js' id="script"></script>
```

Comment: не помогло( он не выключает скрипт в мобильной версии.

Comment: @AsasSas, а что в Вашем понимании "не выключает"? Вы это как проверяете?

Comment: то есть аудиодорожка так и остается в мобильной версии, а появляется она из-за `audioplayer.js`, мне в мобильной нужно его скрывать, чтобы дорожка исчезала.

Comment: @AsasSas, тогда приведите в вопросе воспроизводимый пример - чтобы можно было посмотреть, как и что у Вас работает

Comment: обновил вопрос с кодом. Посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: @AsasSas, ну вот я скопировал Ваш код в песочницу: если менять ширину рабочей области, то плеер прекрасно заменяется на иконку и обратно: https://jsfiddle.net/qnL9et2u/

Comment: да, я так и написал наверху. но у меня тут в коде есть еще `audioplayer.js`, который надо отключать  в мобильной версии, а  в компьютерной версии чтобы работал. Вот мне только это нужно сделать и все. Можете с этим помочь?